# Bash scripting, how to remove trailing substring, case insensitive?

Tags: bash, string, case-insensitive

I am modifying a script that reads in a user email. It is very simple, too simple.

```
echo -n "Please enter your example.com email address: "
read email
email=${email%%@example.com} # removes trailing @example.com from email
echo "email is $email"
```

This works, but only for lower case @example.com. How could I modify this to remove the trailing @example.com, case insensitive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have bash 4:

```
email=${email,,}
email=${email%%@example.com}
```

Otherwise, perhaps just use tr:

```
email=$(echo "${email}" | tr "A-Z" "a-z")
email=${email%%@example.com}
```

**Update**:

If you are just wanting to strip the host (any host) then perhaps this is really what you want:

```
email=${email%%@*}
```

Comment: i dont want to convert the email to lower case. whatever case they enter in, i want to preserve

Comment: It should be noted that both of these will also turn all parts of the address to lower case...

Comment: Maybe you just want this then: email=${email%%@*}

Comment: yea that works. i would select this answer, but you know stack overflow doesnt even let you pick your own answer if you are new.

Answer (score 3):

For Bash 3.2 and greater:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
email='JoHnDoE@eXaMpLe.CoM'
pattern='^(.*)@example.com$'
[[ $email =~ $pattern ]]
email=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}    # result: JoHnDoE
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using sed?

```
email="$(sed 's|@example\.com$||i' <<<"$email")"
```

Note the 'i' flag in the sed substitution command which requests case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another (though a bit lengthy) take on it:

```
email='JoHnDoE@eXaMpLe.CoM'
email=${email%%@[Ee][Xx][Aa][Mm][Pp][Ll][Ee].[Cc][Oo][Mm]}
echo "email is $email"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n "Please enter your example.com email address: "
read _email
_email=$(echo $_email | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="@" }  {print $1}')
echo $_email
```

and for transfer email to lower case you can use declare, such as

declare -l email=$email

Answer (score 0):

Use case insensitive matching to a regular expression:

```
echo -n "Please enter your example.com email address: "
read email
shopt -s nocasematch # Makes comparisons case insensitive
if [[ $email =~ example.com$ ]]; then
    domain=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    echo "email is ${email%%@$domain}"
fi
```

Alternatively, you can cut off a string based on its length (which only makes sense if you know that the user entered the domain correctly):

```
echo -n "Please enter your example.com email address: "
read email
domain=example.com
email_length=${#email}
domain_length=${#domain}
name_length=$(($email_length-$domain_length-1))
email=${email:0:$name_length} # removes trailing @example.com from email
echo "email is $email"
```